# Are Sql Triggers synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, timing

I have a table that has an insert trigger on it. If I insert in 6000 records into this table in one insert statement from a stored procedure, will the stored procedure return before the insert trigger completes?

Just to make sure that I'm thinking correctly, the trigger should only be called (i know 'called' isn't the right word) once because there was only 1 insert statement, right?

My main question is: will the sproc finish even if the trigger hasn't completed?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your insert trigger will run once for the entire insert statement. This is why it is important to use the `inserted` temporary table to see what has actually been inserted, and not just select the most recent single record, or something like that.

I just tested an insert and update trigger and indeed, they are considered part of the insert by sql server. the process will not finish until the trigger finishes.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. I forgot about that, and did exactly what I shouldn't do in a similar situation with a trigger I'm about to deploy. I just re-wrote it to handle the whole insert set from inserted instead of the most recent id. Eek! Could've been a helluva bug. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Triggers are part of the transaction that called them.

One important thing about triggers that you must be aware of is that the trigger fires once for each transaction (at least in SQL server, you should check other dbs, but even if it will process row by row, that is usually a poor idea), so if you insert 6000 records the trigger fires once not 6000 times. Many people are not aware of this and write triggers as if they will process multiple record inserts one record at a time. This is not true and your trigger must account for handing the multiple record insert.

Comment: This depends on trigger definition. In Oracle for example we can demand trigger execution for each row with FOR EACH ROW clause. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm#431

Answer (score 1):

The trigger call is not asynchronous. Each call to your insert procedure will result in the trigger being fired, and the procedure will not return until the trigger finishes.

Take a look at the query plan to see how it works. You'll see that the statements in the trigger will be called for each call to the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, every time the TRIGGER criteria is met, the TRIGGER fires. It fires once in batch processing or Transaction. See my [lesson 101](http://dbalink.wordpress.com/2008/06/20/how-to-sql-server-trigger-101/) on TRIGGER

Answer (score -1):

You should use cursor in insert statement to process trigger row.
Because Triggers in SQL Server fire once per statement, not once per row.

Comment: There is no circumstance where you should use a cursor in a sql server trigger. YOu need to write cursors to presever dat integrity and run as fast as possible. While a cursor might do the first, it fails miserably at the last. You should use set based processing. I don't want to lock up my table for hours while it processes through a cursor something that can take seconds or milliseconds. We removed one her that went from 45 minutes to process 40,000 records to 40 seconds. It is irresponsible to use a cursor in a trigger.