# Will EF call wait for a trigger to finish execution before returning the call?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, triggers

I am using EF 6, and when I make an insert to a table, a trigger may fire.

I want to know, will my insert call wait until the trigger completes its execution before returning the call and executing the next line of my code, or does that trigger happen in a different thread of asynchronously?

Answer (score 3):

I would see: [Are Sql Triggers synchronous or asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210097/are-sql-triggers-synchronous-or-asynchronous)

The gist is that they happen in the same transaction as the rest of the statement.  For your purposes, you won't get a return value unit after the trigger has finished executing.